# swift proper way to hide navigation bar for a specific view

Tags: ios, swift

I simply want to hide the navigation bar for a single view and make my own back-button.

Both of these works, but what are the difference?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Comment: One's animated, the other isn't.

Answer (score 0):

One animates the hiding of the navigation bar, the other doesn't.

You probably would not notice in this case because in viewDidLoad() the navigation bar is not visible yet.